# Using lodash filter I want to replace null with zero

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, sorting, lodash

```
let a = [{'abc': 1, 'qwe':2},{'abc': 2, 'qwe':2},{'abc': 5, 'qwe':null}, {'abc': 4, 'qwe':null}],

let required =  _.chain(a)
                _.groupBy(qwe)
                _.map((value, key) => ({
                 name: key,
                 data: _.map(_.filter(value, item => {
                 return item.qwe;
})
                  'qwe'
                 )
               })).value()
              })
```

output is:

> qwe:[2,2,5]

Expected output is:

> qwe:[2,2,5,0, 0]

Answer (score 0):

If not particular about `loadash`, Here is using `map` and `||` or `??`

```js
let a = [{'abc': 1, 'qwe':2},{'abc': 2, 'qwe':2},{'abc': 5, 'qwe':null}, {'abc': 4, 'qwe':null}];


const get = (arr, key) => arr.map((item) => (item[key] || 0));

console.log(get(a, 'qwe'));
```

Comment: Thanks for the trying this out. But mapping the null, to zero is fine the reason why i am going with the above approach is I have to take a dynamic name and set the values to that specific array

Answer (score 0):

Just map and use `||` to make null to the value you want (here 0)

```js
let a = [
  { abc: 1, qwe: 2 },
  { abc: 2, qwe: 2 },
  { abc: 5, qwe: null },
  { abc: 4, qwe: null },
];

let res = _.chain(a)
  .map("qwe")
  .map((v) => v || 0)
  .value();

console.log(res);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.20/lodash.min.js"></script>
```